# Как вызвать переменную из метода

Tags: python

У меня есть метод punch и в нем я определил рандомное значение damage, как можно его вызвать глобально ?

```
 def punch(self):
        self.damage = random.randint(0,20)
        self.health -= self.damage
```

Comment: Что такое «вызвать глобально»?

Comment: Вне класса. я хочу использовать ее для вывода в print

Comment: Использование `self` намекает, что какой-то экземпляр какого-то класса быть строго обязан. Если вы создали метод для класса, то не очень понятно, чего вы хотите добиться «вне класса»

Comment: Если у вас есть какой-то объект этого класса, то просто делайте `объект.punch(); print(объект.damage)` да и всё

Comment: Покажите класс, тогда можно будет вызвать через объект класса.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 


class game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 100

    def punch(self):
        self.damage = random.randint(0, 20)
        self.health -= self.damage


a = game()
print(a.health)
a.punch()
print(a.health)
print(a.damage)
```

Вывод :
100
86
14

Если Ваш код выглядит примерно так, то получить damage можно так. Вы можете приравнять a.damage к переменной и использовать ее. Если Вы хотите использовать damage в классе, то она Вам доступна, self.damage имеет значение вот наглядно:

```
import random 


class game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 100

    def punch(self):
        self.damage = random.randint(0, 20)
        self.health -= self.damage

    def printer(self):
        print(self.damage)


a = game()
a.punch()
a.printer()
print(a.health)
```

Вывод :
7
93